# Laravel change filesystem disks path on run time

Tags: laravel, laravel-facade, laravel-storage

I am aware of the filesystems.php to create disks and I'm currently using it, having ~~ 20 disks configured.

I have a new problem with these, I'm currently trying to prefix to every disk, a string. The problem is that the paths are being saved when the `php artisan config:cache` is run but I need to change them on run time, as n example, for User `Sergio` it would need to append `Sergio/` to the following disk for example:

```
//filesystems.php
'random' => [
   'driver' => 'local',
   'root' => storage_path('app/random'),
],
```

Then

```
Storage::disk("random")->getDriver()->getAdapter()->getPathPrefix();
//outputs /var/www/html/project/storage/app/random
```

and the goal is setting configurations in for example the middleware i'm currently setting the tentant database already like this

```
//Middleware
Config::set('database.connections.tenant.database', "Sergio");
DB::reconnect('tenant');
```

I can currently set the paths correctly with

```
Config::set('filesystems.disks.random.root',storage_path('app/Sergio/random'));
```

But i'm worried since that if before that line I try to reach to the path, the storage saves the initial path in memory instead of re-fetching it after it is altered.

For example. doing this without any middleware.

```
$fullPath1 = Storage::disk("random")->getDriver()->getAdapter()->getPathPrefix();

Config::set('filesystems.disks.random.root',storage_path('app/Sergio/random'));

$fullPath2 = Storage::disk("random")->getDriver()->getAdapter()->getPathPrefix();
```

What was intended to happen is that `$fullPath1` would output the initial path which is `/var/www/html/project/storage/app/random` and then `$fullPath2` would output `/var/www/html/project/storage/app/Sergio/random`

Is there any way of letting the Storage know that I've changed the disks local paths?

Comment: Any luck? I am getting a similar problem but for an s3 disk. I have few disks and cant change them during runtime, as it always uses the first config :/

Comment: No luck, if for some reason somewhere in the platform the filesystem is accessed before changing, the changes won't take effect

Comment: I am also facing same issue. i want to store file inside storage folder in s3 but not wanted to define root => 'storage' in filesystem config file. help finding out the solution

Answer (score 1):

How about adding a new config instead of updating the already loaded one, something like this:

```
private function addNewDisk(string $diskName) 
{
      config(['filesystems.disk.' . $diskName => [
          'driver' => 'local',
          'root' => storage_path('app/' . $diskName),
      ]]);
}
```

and prior to using the Storage facade, call above method that way the config will be updated and when you use new disk, it will try to resolve again based on updated config.

```
{
....
    $this->addNewDisk('new_random');
    Storage::disk('new_random')->get('abc.txt'); // or any another method
...

}
```